# Does getting all the panels of a Puzzle Swap puzzle do anything?

Tags: puzzle-swap, streetpass-mii-plaza

On Streetpass Mii Plaza, one of the games you can play is Puzzle Swap, where you get pieces either by paying with Play Coins, or by meeting new Miis on Street Pass.

There is a large variety of panels/puzzles, and I was wondering if there was any bonus to completing one, other than just having a nice picture in your collection.

Is there some sort of bonus here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only bonus is that you get to look at a pretty picture that moves in 3D. For a Nintendo fan, they are pretty neat.

With that said though I would spend my coins on the find mii games before giving your coins to the puzzles, personally having all the different hats was a more worthwhile goal to achieve compared to the randomness of the puzzles.

Comment: Moves in 3D? Like an animation?

Comment: Yep, they are pretty neat. Some move a lot and some your able to pan and zoom around.

Comment: I wonder if this is similar to the xbox arcade game called "Swap"?

Comment: @Ashley: The completed images can be viewed here: http://nintendo.wikia.com/wiki/Puzzle_Swap It also links to a YouTube video that shows what they unlock...

Comment: They are like [dioramas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diorama) with a little bit of motion.